# Using a FROM Clause to Join two Queries into a Sub-Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to combine two queries into one uncorrelated expression using the `FROM` clause. I have attempted to mimic the lesson plan examples from the book, but I keep getting an error regarding my join.

The error is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

I assume this means that I am VERY far off on my approach.

**The two queries are:**

```
     SELECT Product.product_id, product.product_name
     FROM Product
     JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
     GROUP BY product.product_id, product.product_name
     HAVING COUNT(sells.store_location_id) = 5;


     SELECT Product.product_name, Sizes.Size_option
     FROM Product
     JOIN Available_in ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
     JOIN Sizes ON  Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
```

**My Current Code is:**

```
     SELECT Product.product_name, Sizes.Size_option
     FROM (SELECT Sells.product_id
          FROM Sells
          JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
          GROUP BY Sells.product_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 5)
     JOIN Available_in ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id 
     JOIN Sizes ON Available_in.Sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id;
```

Comment: Your queries really make no sense.  You should ask another question with sample data, desired results, an explanation of what you want to do, and sample code.

Answer (score 2):

"Product" won't be available outside the derived table for joining, Modify code as follows : -

```
 SELECT Temp.product_name, Sizes.Size_option
 FROM (SELECT Sells.product_id
      FROM Sells
      JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
      GROUP BY Sells.product_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 5) Temp
 JOIN Available_in ON Temp.product_id = Available_in.product_id 
 JOIN Sizes ON Available_in.Sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id;
```

Comment: yep, op missed the aliasing

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error may be due to missing alias for your subquery `(SELECT sells....)`.  I would approach it by converting the first query into a subquery (products that are sold in 5 locations) and give it the alias `Product` and join it to the 2nd query:

```
SELECT Product.product_name, Sizes.Size_option
FROM 
-- first query --
(SELECT Product.product_id, product.product_name
 FROM Product
 JOIN Sells on Sells.product_id = product.product_id
 GROUP BY product.product_id, product.product_name
 HAVING COUNT(sells.store_location_id) = 5) Product

 JOIN Available_in ON Product.product_id = Available_in.product_id
 JOIN Sizes ON  Available_in.sizes_id = Sizes.sizes_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current query has multiple errors, because you have `sales` twice in the subquery.

If I understand correctly, you can write the query as:

```
 SELECT p.product_name, s.Size_option
 FROM (SELECT s.product_id
       FROM Sells s 
       GROUP BY s.product_id
       HAVING COUNT(*) = 5
      ) sp JOIN
      Available_in a
      ON sp.product_id = a.product_id JOIN
      Sizes s
      ON ai.Sizes_id = s.sizes_id JOIn
      Products p
      ON p.product_id = a.product_id;
```